# @Autowired field is null in one SpringMVC controller while others work

Tags: spring-mvc

I've a quite simple and classic page with a Spring MVC controller and a jsp (the JSP is not relevant here):

```
@Controller
public class PlayListListController  extends BaseController<PlayList> {

    @Autowired UserRepository userRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/playlist/{userName}")
    private ModelAndView displayList(@PathVariable("userName") String userName) {
        User user = userRepository.getUserByUserName(userName);
        ....
    }

}
```

My problem is the following. When I want to access my page with the URL: `http://localhost:8080/playlist/foo` it throws a NullPointeurException in the controller at line 8.

```
    User user = userRepository.getUserByUserName(userName);
```

When debugging, I see that userRepository is indeed null.

userRepository is supposed to be injected by Spring, and in all my other controllers, it happens fine: the same bean (userRepository) is correctly injected by Sptring.

Why in this specific controller (which is in the same package as all the others) which is instantiated and called by Spring, userRepository is null?
I don't understand at all. Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks!
Emile.

Comment: By any chance you declared PlayListListController as a xml bean in your spring cpnfig ? Also if you can share your spring config please

Comment: How is the context configured?

Answer (score 7):

I found the answer when i proceed this way: I created a @PostConstruct method in the controler to see if userRepository was injected at the beginning. Indeed, when the @PostConstruct method was running, userRepository was not null. While debugging my methodi found that the id of the object
( in the view variable on eclipse ) was 307. Besides, when debugging displayList method, "this" shown a proxy. SO, it looks like @postconstruct method test () is running in the bean whime @RequestMapping displayList method is running in the proxy. In the proxy, userRepository would be null.

So why @RequestMapping displayList () is running in the proxy ?
The reason is my method was **private**. If i turn displayList() into a public method, everything works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas:

- Turn on Spring logging to the INFO level and you should see some logging statements during app startup that tell you which controllers got mapped to which URLs. See if this controller is listed. If not, it's not getting recognized as a controller by spring.
- Have you declared this controller in a namespace that is not scanned by the `<context:component-scan>` tag in your xml?
- As @coder mentions, ensure the bean isn't being declared in your XML context already